# Optimize SQL, same line multiple times in CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-optimization

I've written a SQL Servre stored procedure (SQL Server 2014) that looks at a certain column in a certain table, if the result is null I want to take the value from an other column.

I've ended up with writing this line twice:

```
(Select t_EC 
 from TTCIB 
 where rtrim(ltrim(t_item)) = rtrim(ltrim(t1.t_item)) 
   and t_comp = '50')
```

Once to check if it is null.

And the second time to actually add the value to my result if it wasn't null.

Is there a way to optimize this? So that the system doesn't need to run this line twice? (it has ltrim function twice and rtrim function twice so it would be useful)

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 15 
    (SELECT t_EC 
     FROM TTCIB 
     WHERE rtrim(ltrim(t_item)) = rtrim(ltrim(t1.t_item)) 
       AND t_comp = '18') as EC18,
    CASE 
       WHEN (SELECT t_EC FROM TTCIB 
             WHERE rtrim(ltrim(t_item)) = rtrim(ltrim(t1.t_item)) 
               AND t_comp = '50') IS NULL
          THEN (SELECT t_EC 
                FROM TTCIB 
                WHERE rtrim(ltrim(t_item)) = rtrim(ltrim(t1.t_item)) 
                  AND t_comp = '51')
          ELSE (SELECT t_EC 
                FROM TTCIB 
                WHERE rtrim(ltrim(t_item)) = rtrim(ltrim(t1.t_item)) 
                  AND t_comp = '50') 
    END AS EC50,
    RTRIM(t1.t_sern) AS SerialNumber, t1.t_item AS Item, 
    RTRIM(t1.t_desc) AS ItemDesc, t1.t_ofbp AS SoldToBP,    
    RTRIM(t2.t_nama) AS BPName, t1.t_cwte AS Warranty, 
    t1.t_dltm AS DeliveryTime, t_optm AS InstallationTime,   
    t_clst AS Cluster, ISNULL(t3.t_endt,'1970-01-01') AS EndDate,
    t4.t_csig as ItemSignalCode, t5.t_dsca as ItemSignalCodeDesc  
FROM 
    FnGetSerialNos(@SerialNumber, @MasterCompany) t1  
INNER JOIN 
    ttccom100900 t2 ON t1.t_ofbp = t2.t_bpid
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ttsctm120900 t3 ON t1.t_term = t3.t_term
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ttcibd001900 t4 ON ltrim(t1.t_item) = ltrim(t4.t_item)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ttcmcs018900 t5 ON t4.t_csig = t5.t_csig
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some non-ANSI SQL there.)

Comment: Uncorrelated sub-queries... Your query can probably be completely re-written. Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Where is the rest of your query?

Comment: show a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: Can you also please post the create table scripts, which will tell us which table these columns do belong too

Comment: 1) Top w/o an order by makes no sense.  2) Seems like coalesce would work better there... take first non-null value in a series of comma separated values..

Answer (score 0):

Use an INNER JOIN to read all relevant values from `TTCIB`, and use a `COALESCE()` function instead of `CASE WHEN ... END`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 15 
         x.t_18 as EC18
        ,COALESCE(x.t_50, x.t_51) AS EC50
        ,RTRIM(t1.t_sern) AS SerialNumber
        ,t1.t_item AS Item
        ,RTRIM(t1.t_desc) AS ItemDesc
        ,t1.t_ofbp AS SoldToBP
        ,RTRIM(t2.t_nama) AS BPName
        ,t1.t_cwte AS Warranty
        ,t1.t_dltm AS  DeliveryTime
        ,t_optm AS InstallationTime
        ,t_clst AS Cluster
        , ISNULL(t3.t_endt,'1970-01-01') AS EndDate
        ,t4.t_csig as ItemSignalCode
        , t5.t_dsca as ItemSignalCodeDesc  
FROM FnGetSerialNos(@SerialNumber, @MasterCompany) t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT   RTRIM(LTRIM(t_EC)) AS t_EC
                ,MAX(CASE WHEN t_comp = '18' THEN t_EC END) AS t_18
                ,MAX(CASE WHEN t_comp = '50' THEN t_EC END) AS t_50
                ,MAX(CASE WHEN t_comp = '51' THEN t_EC END) AS t_51
        FROM TTCIB
        GROUP BY t_EC
    ) x
        ON RTRIM(LTRIM(t1.t_item)) = x.t_EC
    INNER JOIN ttccom100900 t2  
        ON t1.t_ofbp = t2.t_bpid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ttsctm120900 t3  
        ON t1.t_term = t3.t_term
    Left Outer JOIN ttcibd001900 t4  
        ON ltrim(t1.t_item) = ltrim(t4.t_item)
    Left Outer JOIN ttcmcs018900 t5  
        ON t4.t_csig = t5.t_csig
;
```

Answer (score 0):

faster(for all kinds of db)

```
coalesce((Select t_EC from TTCIB where rtrim(ltrim(t_item)) = rtrim(ltrim(t1.t_item)) and t_comp = '50'),(Select t_EC from TTCIB where rtrim(ltrim(t_item)) = rtrim(ltrim(t1.t_item)) and t_comp = '51')) as EC50
```

fastest(only for sqlserver, oracle with this method is quite complex)

```
(Select top 1 t_EC from TTCIB where rtrim(ltrim(t_item)) = rtrim(ltrim(t1.t_item)) and t_comp in ('50','51') order by t_comp asc) as EC50
```